# Defining custom compare function for std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am trying to make a character frequency map that, on every insert, puts the character with the highest frequency at the start of the map.

So, it would be like a `std::map<char, int>` and I would iterate the string and do `map[string[i]]++` to increment the frequency count for each character. On every increment, the map would sort itself like a priority queue and put the key-value pair with the highest frequency at the beginning of the map so I can retrieve with `map.begin()`.

I tried to make a custom comparator for `std::map`, but some incomprehensible error messages came out.

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct cmpByValue
{
    bool operator()(const pair<char, int>& p1, const pair<char, int>& p2)
    {
        return p1.second > p2.second;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    map<char, int, cmpByValue> freq_map;
    string s = "ASDASDASD";
    for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
    {
        freq_map[s[i]]++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that `std::map` automatically sorts the elements based on the keys, but since I want it to sort by frequency, it would have to sort by value instead of key.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: A `map` only cares about the keys. I don't think it even knows how to look at the ... eff it. Why don't I look at the error message? https://godbolt.org/z/8n3svhvnW Looks like my thinking was right: **no match for call to '(cmpByValue) (const char&, const char&)'** It doesn't compare the `pair`s, just the keys.

Comment: And yeah, that's pretty close to incomprehensible. You're going to have to learn how to read this gobble-dee-gook. It mostly comes with practice. [Out of the big three](https://godbolt.org/z/Ebxexa5Ga), I think Microsoft gives the easiest-to-read diagnostic. Sometimes it's worth dropping the code into different compilers to see if one of them gives a better diagnostic. Better being the one you can more-easily understand.

Comment: *On every increment, the map would sort itself like a priority queue* -- [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: @user4581301 I thought it was pretty readable as error messages go.

Comment: @RetiredNinja As far as template crawls go, yes. That one earns a gold star. But we should strive to do better. This is one of my big hopes for AI in compilers. "Map can only compare based on the key, never the value. Now how about a nice game of chess?"

Comment: @user4581301 Could bring whole new meaning to undefined behavior. :)

Comment: You might want to look up [Boost Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html), which supports this sort of thing (unlike anything in the standard library).

Comment: One other note: there's not really a whole lot of point in using a `std::map<char, int>`. I'd just use a `vector<int>(std::limits<uint8_t>::max());`. That's only going to be a kilobyte or 2 at most, so using a tree to get sparse storage will often lose more than it gains.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin – I see how this would work when tabulating counts. I also understand you could use `std::max_element` to find the letter with the highest count. But what do you do if you want to sort based on count, so you can print a frequency table? Perhaps the vector should be a vector of structs, something like: `struct LetterCount { std::uint8_t letter; int count; };`.

Comment: @tbxfreeware: When I've done it, I started with an array, then when I'd counted all the input characters, inserted the data into an array of structs with the letter and count, then sorted that based on counts. Given that it's only 256 elements, that copy isn't a big deal.

Comment: "I tried to make a custom comparator for std::map, but some incomprehensible error messages came out." - what error messages *exactly*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are attempting to do with `std::map` (or any associative container, for that matter) is simply not feasible, as it sorts its elements on *keys* only, not on their mapped values. You can't make `std::map` move its elements around when the values change, only when the keys change.

So, you will have to sort your `std::map` elements *after* you are done calculating all of the frequency values, eg:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

using freqMap = map<char, int>;
using freqMapElement = typename map<char, int>::value_type;

bool cmpByValue(const freqMapElement* p1, const freqMapElement* p2)
{
    return p1->second > p2->second;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "ASDASDASD";

    freqMap freq_map;
    for (auto c : s)
    {
        freq_map[c]++;
    }

    vector<freqMapElement*> freq_vec;
    freq_vec.reserve(freq_map.size());
    for (auto &elem : freq_map)
    {
        freq_vec.push_back(&elem);
    }
    sort(freq_vec.begin(), freq_vec.end(), cmpByValue);

    freqMapElement* top = *freq_vec.begin();
    // use top as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/3TRxnS)

---

That being said - since you stated:

> On every increment, the map would sort itself **like a priority queue** and put the key-value pair with the highest frequency at the beginning of the map so I can retrieve with `map.begin()`.

Then you could simply use `std::priority_queue` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

using freqMap = map<char, int>;
using freqMapElement = typename freqMap::value_type;

struct cmpByValue
{
    bool operator()(const freqMapElement* p1, const freqMapElement* p2)
    {
        return p1->second > p2->second;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string s = "ASDASDASD";

    freqMap freq_map;
    for (auto c : s)
    {
        freq_map[c]++;
    }

    priority_queue<
        freqMapElement*,
        std::vector<freqMapElement*>,
        cmpByValue> pq;

    for (auto &elem : freq_map)
    {
        pq.push(&elem);
    }

    freqMapElement* top = pq.top();
    // use top as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ni4b6d)